# Tensorflow clip values in collection?

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, batch-updates

I am trying to clip all training variables for my discriminators in my network.

I get the variables for the discriminators like this:

```
A_d_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'A_d_')
B_d_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'A_B_')
discriminatorVars = self.A_d_vars + self.B_d_vars
```

Now, if I try to do this
`discriminatorVars.assign(tf.clip_by_value(discriminatorVars, 0.01, 0.1))` to clip all the values to [0.01, 0.1] it won't work as the vars are python lists not tensors.

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
self.sess.run(tf.map_fn(lambda var: var.assign(tf.clip_by_value(var, 0.01, 0.1)), var_list))
```

It says that `list` object has no `assign` method.

Currently I loop through all the variables in the list and call `self.sess.run(var.assign(tf.clip_by_value(var, 0.01, 0.1)))`
The problem is that is very slow.

How can I batch-update the collections so their values will be clipped?

Answer (score 1):

Try making a list of the assign ops you want to do, and use `tf.group` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group) to group them. Pass the `tf.group` operator to `sess.run`.

`Session.run()` can have a non-trivial overhead, so you want to do all the updates in a single `Session.run()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am pretty new to tensorflow, could you also write an example of how `tf.group` can be used?